# Duplication in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

So, I've been wondering about this for a while, because if it doesn't work for this new game I'm going to manually have to create hundreds of different movieclips. So, here is what I want to know:

Say if I was developing a game about "Ice Cream" Where you have to create different scoops for your customers.To get an ice cream cone you click the cone and one generates, you can drag it. How do I do this? What I would usually do is create a hundred ice cream cones, make them all invisible, and when it's clicked make the first one visible and if it's clicked again, see if the first one is visible and make the second one visible and so forth. I obviously know they are is an easier way.. but I don't know what that is.

I heard about Duplicating Movie Clips but I read somewhere that it was removed in AS3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible and quite easy in fact.

1) Click an object and get the class name.

2) Create an new instance of that class and put it in the display list.

3) Move that new instance on every frame to the mouse coordinates until you detect the `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP` event.

You will have to tweak the code to fit your project, but this it how it goes. I haven't tested it, but it should work.

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

var duplicate;
var className;

original.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,duplicateMe);

public function duplicateMe(event):void {
    className:Class = Class(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(event.target)));
    duplicate = new className;
    addChild(duplicate);
    duplicate.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,endDrag);
    duplicate.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ENTER_FRAME,update);
}       


public function update(event):void {
    event.target.x = mouseX;
    event.target.y = mouseY;
}

public function endDrag(event):void {
    event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ENTER_FRAME,update);                    
}
```

Comment: Thanks! To be honest I'm not a big user of classes, could you help with some of the code? Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0):

The movieclip type is like the blue print of a movieclip. One can create as many of those movieclips as one needs. For example the movieclip type cat can have an instance with the name Simba. So:

```
var Simba:Cat = new Cat();
```

In flash you can simply select the right export to actionscript option to export the type.